# How do I recursively search through directories and remove open/close brackets from filenames without using the rename command?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find, file-rename

I have an issue where I need to remove all open [ and close ] brackets from every filename on disk. The solution has to work on systems without the rename command available.

For an example file structure that looks like this:

```
/file [name].ext
/test[file].example
/nobracket.nrml
/path/to/subdirectory/deep [bracket].test
/[test] brackets with - spaces.sample
```

I'd need the result to look like:

```
/file name.ext
/testfile.example
/no bracket.nrml
/path/to/subdirectory/deep bracket.test
/test brackets with - spaces.sample
```

1 of 2 approaches I've tried:

```
for i in `find . -type f -name '*[*'` ; do mv $i `echo $i | sed 's/\[//g'` ; done
```

it hangs up on files with spaces and, in addition to not performing the rename, gives this output:

```
mv: can't rename './[test]': No such file or directory
mv: can't rename 'brackets': No such file or directory
mv: can't rename 'with': No such file or directory
mv: can't rename '-': No such file or directory
mv: can't rename 'spaces.sample': No such file or directory
```

2 of 2 approaches I've tried:

```
find . -type f -name '*[*' -exec sed 's/[][]//g' {} \+
```

In addition to not renaming files, this approach returns odd output to stdout, that looks like this:

```
ȏkgn7Y{/        fpu(?{yw-M^?}r& @n
        cȌ      ; @vk@ș<1㙀9'{ݥfn7y`L}|t;&! x|}{1r       '@r     '@r     '@r     '@r     '@r     '@r     '@r     '@r{=?>hO)& @N @N @N @N9>wx/& @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N @N89W=CZzǏhjss6ju@7W?Gub
```

Any insight into how to solve this would be very much appreciated! One-liners would be ideal but open to other solutions.

Comment: Use the `rename` command. It has a recursive option.

Answer (score 1):

Since your filenames have spaces, you need to quote the command substitution. Otherwise, it will be parsed as multiple arguments.

Also, you're having the same problem with the output of `find`, it's being split into separate names at the whitespace by `for`. Pipe it to a `while read` loop instead of using `for`.

There's no need to use `sed` since `bash` has a built-in replacement operator. This operator takes a wildcard pattern to look for, so you can use `[\[\]]` to match either bracket.

```
find . -type f -name '*[*' | while read -r f; do
    mv "$f" "${f//[\[\]]/}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out why the solutions I'd tried weren't working. Your solution is great for replacing just the [ but I was hoping for an all-in-one that could do [ and ]. Is there a way to do that with this replacement method?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to replace both brackets.